# PrimeFaces 5.1 doesn't display chart in p:fieldset

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem, when I am using `<p:chart>` inside a `<p:fieldset>`, it doesn't appear but if I remove `<p:set>`, it appears. Is it not possible to use these components together in this version of PrimeFaces?

Answer (score 0):

You can just enclose the `<p:chart>` component with a deferred `<p:outputPanel>`:

```
<p:fieldset legend="#{msg['label.totalSpace']}" >
    <p:outputPanel deferred="true">
        <p:chart type="bar" model="#{officeManager.usageBarChartModel}" />
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:fieldset>
```